# PHP - Change text URL to real URL in string

Tags: php, regex

I have strings:

```
$string1 = 'Hi John. Please, go to my website http://www.google.com :)';
$string2 = 'See this :P www.imgurl.com/abcd.jpg';
```

How can I convert this strings to:

```
$string1 = 'Hi John. Please, go to my website <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a> :)';
$string2 = 'See this :P <img src="http://www.imgurl.com/abcd.jpg" alt ="" />';
```

I dont know ;(

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be to use a regular expression to replace your URL with either the `<a>` Tag or the `<img>` Tag. The tricky part will be to determine whether it is an image or a normal URL.

Read here about PHP preg_replace function: https://www.php.net/preg_replace

And here is a list of regular expressions to match URLs: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1